# Recommended brands for full-day rides and short multi-day tours

Tags: touring-bikes

I’m going to be investing in a new touring bike soon for weekly centuries and the occasional few-day tour. I’m looking at the $2K or possibly $3K level.

I currently ride a *Lemond Croix de Fer*, and I like the comments I get from others who notice I’m riding a *LeMond*. So I find myself wanting to look beyond the common brands like Specialized and Trek. My question: is it reasonable to look beyond the common brands for a bike that is more "specialized" than Specialized?

Comment: I do feel the brand is not as important as the fit of a bike, fit in size but also in what you want of it in performance. So look for the bike that fits your cycling style, needs and your body.

Comment: Concur - if the bike is not a good fit then nothing else matters.  For a touring bike you want features like fender/rack mounts.  I'd look for something with longer trail and longer chainstays.  You might also explore unusual handlebars for more hand positions.

Comment: I'm scheduled next week for the first of three visits to a professional bike fitter.  After the first visit, he generates a bike CAD design for me to use when selecting and ordering a bike.  So I have the 'fit' part in place - my next decision is in what brands to consider (or prefer).

Comment: The common belief here is that all brands are the same and all product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: If you get comments while riding, you're not riding hard enough :-)   We strongly recommend brands with round wheels, as opposed to any other shape.   But seriously - such topics are better left for chatty web forums.  SE is a Q&A format for problems, and "what brand" is a sales question that will be obsolete pretty quickly.  You might want to try [chat] because that expires quickly and is way less structured.

Answer (score 3):

Specific product recommendations are off topic here, but the answer to your general question is *yes*, it's fine to look beyond the biggest bicycle producers (Trek Specialized, Giant, Cannondale etc.)

Surly and Salsa are two brands that offer touring oriented frames that come to mind. (Note, I offer these as examples, not recommendations).